# time .bat file run time

Tags: windows, batch-file, time

I'm very new with .bat files! But a quick learner.

I'm an engineering student and am working with a wave simulation model. I need to time the computation time, and am trying to do this by setting a variable `StartTime=%time%` just before I run the simulation, and after the simulation has ended I set `EndTime=%time%`, and with this I want to calculate the computation time. I run the model by opening a .bat file `swashcmd.bat` and changing the directory to the folder with my input file `file_name.sws` and then using the command `swashrun file_name.sws`.

I've tried to make a .bat file that I run from `swashcmd.bat`

```
@echo off

cd %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Bachelor\SWASH\testcases\Compiled\a11stwav

set StartTime=%time%

swashrun a11stw01

echo Computation done

set EndTime=%time%
```

This changes the directory and runs the simulation, but I can't verify that anything afterwards is carried out.

I've tried to make a .bat file that opens `swashcmd.bat`, and runs the simulation

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\swash\
swashcmd.bat

cd C:\Users\dk46739\Dropbox\Bachelor\SWASH\testcases\Compiled\a11stwav
```

This starts the `swashcmd.bat` but does not change the directory.

It is beyond me to change anything in `swashcmd.bat`. Is it possible to do what I want without changing the `swashcmd.bat` file? And which way around (running a .bat from `swashcmd.bat` or running `swashcmd.bat` from a .bat) is better? (and why)
^

## Opdate 1

With call

```
cd C:\Program Files\swash\
call swashcmd.bat

cd C:\Users\dk46739\Dropbox\Bachelor\SWASH\testcases\Compiled\a11stwav
```

Stops after calling `swashcmd.bat`

## Opdate 2

Tried calling my .bat file from `swashcmd.bat` with `cal`. `EndTime` is not stored. Expanding the bat file to output star and end time to a .txt file when saving start and end time works.

Comment: `getTimestamp.bat` is a helper batch file to manipulate and measure all sorts of time and date variables and can be found here - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27422#p27422 and it can calculate the elapsed time in varied manners.  If your wave simulation is in the order of 5 to 10 seconds then the latency in running batch files could be an issue.

Comment: If `swashrun` is a batch file too, you need to execute it with a `call` command so that the execution returns to `swashcmd` and `set EndTime=...` is executed eventually. Also, you are storing both times but are never displaying them (or so it seems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see what is echoed to the screen and if the pause command is reached:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Program Files\swash\"
call swashcmd.bat
echo "%starttime%"
echo "%endtime%"
echo pause 2
pause
cd /d "C:\Users\dk46739\Dropbox\Bachelor\SWASH\testcases\Compiled\a11stwav"
```

Try this one too - and tell us if any error messages are on the screen, and if the pause command is reached:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Bachelor\SWASH\testcases\Compiled\a11stwav"
set StartTime=%time%
call swashrun a11stw01
echo Computation done
set EndTime=%time%
echo pause 1
pause
```

Comment: `swashcmd.bat` is called, but `starttime` and `endtime` is not stored and pause is not reached.

Comment: Something in `swashcmd.bat` is the issue if no errors are on the screen.  Is `swashrun` a batch file too?  If so then use `call swashrun a11stw01`

Comment: using `call swashrun %inputfile%` works, thank you !! start and end time is stored and pause is reached without eny errors.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
CALL swashcmd.bat
```

Otherwise, control is not returned to the caller.